# How to reduce number of queries testing uniqueness in django?

Tags: python, sql, django

Say I have a model:

```
class User(models.Model):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True)
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
```

When I create a `User`, django needs to first check the unique constraints and does so with two individual queries like

```
SELECT (1) AS "a" FROM "accounts_user" WHERE "accounts_user"."username" = 'aoeu' LIMIT 1

SELECT (1) AS "a" FROM "accounts_user" WHERE "accounts_user"."email" = 'aoeu@aoeu.com' LIMIT 1
```

How do I tell django to check both constraints in one query like

```
SELECT (1) AS "a" FROM "accounts_username" WHERE "accounts_user"."username" = 'aoeu' OR "accounts_user"."email" = 'aoeu@aoeu.com' LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no simple way to tell Django to only do one query in this case. You could stop using the Django model form validation, and write your own raw SQL queries. However, it's probably not worth it to save a single SQL query.

You could dig in to the Django source code, and try to optimise where the uniqueness constraint checks are generated. If you get it working, you could submit it as a patch.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can use `Q objects` to do that. 
Here is documentation reference: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects

Then `Q(username='aoeu') | Q(email='aoeu@aoeu.com')` will be equal to `WHERE username = 'aoeu' OR email = 'aoeu@aoeu.com'`